# To decrease the level of volume in iPod touch

Tags: ipod-touch

I have my volume at the lowest level at `Settings > Music > Volume Limit` and at `Settings > General > Sounds` the volume bar at the very bottom too.

I open a song at Music. I change the volume by the two buttons at the left corner of the iPod.
The volume is at the lowest level and it is still too high.

**Is there any way to decrease the level of the volume?**

Comment: I've noticed the same issue with my 3rd gen Touch.  I wish there were a bit more granularity in the volume control.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not an answer, but addition to the original post by another.

I'm having the same issue here with the Apple's original in-ear(?) headphone included with the itouch itself.

There are two sliders about the sound volume set to lowest as same as he did. But nothing turns fine.

Listening to music with the level of the sound volume I mention actually, I have to take a rest for 1 hour after 15 minutes listening.

Of course, songs include ones downloaded from iTunes store.
Even some of the rest seem to be made by iTunes as mentioned in its tags.

And even while playing videos, playing games using a headphone happen the same.

So that normalizing the average levels of sound volumes of the sound files is not a perfect answer.
We'd love to modify **the least level of the system-wide sound volume** instead.
And that is the only way to solve the problem, I think.

Answer (score 2):

This may depend on the headphones you attach to the iPod. If your headphones are not-standard headphones and you want to keep them, you could buy a volume attenuator for a few bucks.

Is this the case for every song or album you play? It may be the case that the volumne level wasn't set properly during the encoding.

You could try to adjust the level using an open-source software like [mp3gain](http://mp3gain.sourceforge.net/):

> Tired of reaching for your volume knob
>   every time your mp3 player changes to
>   a new song? MP3Gain analyzes and
>   adjusts mp3 files so that they have
>   the same volume.

Comment: It is the case in every song. All songs are from official CDs by Sony and other firms.